# Attempting to marshal and unmarshal libp2p AddrInfo

Tags: go, gob, go-libp2p

I am using the libp2p Go library to make a p2p networking stack.

I need to unicast messages to other peers on my network. I want to store the AddrInfo struct on my message I unicast so I can send a response back.

**The below is libp2p library code:**

The AddrInfo struct contains

```
type ID string

// AddrInfo is a small struct used to pass around a peer with
// a set of addresses (and later, keys?).
type AddrInfo struct {
    ID    ID
    Addrs []ma.Multiaddr
}
```

Multiaddr is as follows

```
type Multiaddr interface {
    json.Marshaler
    json.Unmarshaler
    encoding.TextMarshaler
    encoding.TextUnmarshaler
    encoding.BinaryMarshaler
    encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler
}
```

**This is my code using the libp2p library:**

I include this in my message struct like so

```
func init() {
    gob.Register(&Message{})
}

// Message stores a type of message and a body.
// The message is the data that gets passed between nodes when they communicate.
type Message struct {
    ID         string           `json:"id"`
    Body       []byte           `json:"body"`        // the actual payload.
    OriginNode peer.AddrInfo    `json:"origin_node"` // the node that sent the message
}

// NewMessage builds up a new message.
func NewMessage(b []byte, o peer.AddrInfo) Message {
    return Message{
        ID:        uuid.New().String(),
        Body:      b,
        OriginNode: o,
    }
}

// Marshal takes a node message and marshals it into an array of bytes.
func (m Message) Marshal() []byte {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)

    if err := enc.Encode(m); err != nil {
        zap.S().Fatal(err)
    }

    return buf.Bytes()
}

// UnmarshalMessage takes a slice of bytes and a returns a message struct.
func UnmarshalMessage(input []byte) (Message, error) {
    msg := Message{}
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(input)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)

    if err := dec.Decode(&msg); err != nil {
        return Message{}, err
    }

    return msg, nil
}
```

When I marshal my message struct and then attempt to unmarshal I receive the following error:

> ```
> panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler [recovered]
>         panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler
> UnmarshalMessage(0xc0001c7200, 0x454, 0x480, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
> ```

I can't edit the libp2p source code but need the AddrInfo within my struct.

Comment: do you need the that encoder decoder struct there?

Comment: which part of code can't you edit?

Comment: The AddrInfo and MultiAddr